# Allows User Login to Exchange OWA On-Prem Using Primary Email Address Instead of UPN

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, exchange-2019

I am trying to find out if there is a way for users to login to our Exchange 2019 CAS server OWA using their primary email address instead of their UPN.  For some reason when Exchange was first setup here (before my time) they went with a different format to the user's login.  Our login (UPN) is just the user's first name (ie: test@contoso.com) but the email address is first initial/last name (ie: tuser@contoso.com).  This is NOT a UPN suffix issue as both suffixes are the same (ie: @contoso.com).  I can login to OWA using the UPN just fine but not using the email address.  Does Exchange allow this?

Comment: Agree with Joeqwerty

Comment: Exchange 2019 does not support. The UPN is the primary identifier for a user in Active Directory and is used for authentication purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, that isn't possible. But you can change the UPN to match the email address with no detrimental effect.

[image]